# ActionMode not working as intended with a listview embeded in a ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, android-appcompat, actionmode

My fragment contains a viewpager, which contains a listView

This listView rows display a thumbnail on the left and some text on the right.
Like the gmail app, when I press on the thumbnail I want it to switch to the actionmode. When pressing elsewhere it opens a different activity related to the specific row pressed on.
This part works fine.

In my adapter I have the following code

```
viewHolder.getImage().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                documentFragments.setActionMode(true);
            }
        });
```

then in my fragment I have the following code

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void setActionMode(final boolean enabled) {
    if (enabled && this.actionModeEnabled) {
        return;
    }

    if (!enabled && !this.actionModeEnabled) {
        return;
    }

    this.currentAdapter.setActionModeEnabled(enabled);
    if (enabled) {
        this.listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        this.listView.startActionMode(new ActionMode.Callback() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(final ActionMode mode, final Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
SOME CODE

                }

                @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(final ActionMode mode, final Menu menu) {
                mode.setTitle(getActivity().getString(R.string.selectDocuments));
                getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.documents_action_menu, menu);

                // force the checkbox display
                DocumentsFragment.this.currentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(final ActionMode mode, final MenuItem item) {
 SOME CODE
                }
            });
    } else {
        this.listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
    }
    this.actionModeEnabled = enabled;
}
```

So when I press on the thumbnail everything works fine, I display a checkbox on the row and the actionMode option menu is displayed on the appcompat I'm using.
Now what I want is press anywhere on the listview row to select/unselect rows.
That's where it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
private void initControls() {
    this.listView = (ListView) this.view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    registerForContextMenu(this.listView);
    this.listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
        if (this.actionModeEnabled) {
            final boolean isChecked = this.listView.isItemChecked(position);
 DO SOMETHING
        } else {
 DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
```

When not in actionMode onItemClick is called, but once in actionMode it's not called anymore...

How can I receive the information that a row has been clicked on when in action mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the CheckBox in the row layout with a CheckedTextView and everything works fine now.